# CVS branch actual location on server

Tags: version-control, cvs, cvs2svn

The  CVS repository in my project has a HEAD code and 8 other branches. The server location mentioned as '/local/cvs/srcjboss' contains only the projects in the HEAD branch.

Is there a physical location on the server where all the branch code can be accessed ? I need the server location for CVS to SVN migration.

If it helps, we are using a linux server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a CVS history to Subversion using cvs2svn, you need filesystem-level access to the data from the central CVS repository.  It is *not* enough to have access to a working copy where the code is checked out.  It's not really clear from your question which of these you have under `/local/cvs/srcjboss`.

A CVS repository is recognizable from its CVSROOT subdirectory and lots of files named like your project files, but with ",v" appended, like maybe "Makefile,v" or "index.html,v" or "build.xml,v".  Each of these files contains the entire history (including branches) of the corresponding file from your project, in rcsfile(5) format.  The repository probably also contains "Attic" subdirectories that hold the histories of files that are not present in HEAD.

A CVS working copy, on the other hand, contains one particular version of each file (with no ",v" suffix), plus a `CVS` subdirectory in each of your project directory.  A CVS working copy doesn't contain any of the project history.

So is your `/local/cvs/srcjboss` the CVS repository or is it a working copy?

If you have a working copy and are trying to find the central repository, look in one of the files named `CVS/Root`.  It will tell you the location of the repository from which the working copy was checked out.

Comment: Thanks mhagger .. I checked and found the history in all the (,v)files. Looks like CVS stores the branches as a single repository and not as as separate physical directories that can be accessed with a path/url